# comparing string literals in c++ templates

Tags: c++, string, templates, compare, literals

I wrote a template function to compare two variables:

```
template <class t>

int compare(const t &a, const t &b) {

if(a>b) return 1;

if (a<b) return -1;

return 0;

}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    cout << compare("hi","world");

    return 0;

}
```

I get the following error

```
../src/templates.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
../src/templates.cpp:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘compare(const char [3], const char [6])
```

Please explain.
Also if I write `cout << compare("hi", "wo");` it compiles properly.
Or if I remove the `&` and declare the function like `int compare(const t a, const t b)` it compiles.

Comment: Remember, as with C, the `char *` string type cannot be compared using the operators; you have to use `strcmp` or something similar.  Otherwise, you are comparing the **pointers** not the contents of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string literal of N characters is an array of N constant characters with a terminating '\0' afterwards. So type of `"hi"` is `char const[3]` and the one of `"world"` is `char const[6]`.

So if you pass it to the template, `t` is deduced to two different types. Note that when in a reference parameter, template argument deduction does not transform arrays to pointers.

Also, please check up in comparing pointers to each other. The way you do that won't ever compare the strings lexically, but just the addresses of them, yielding an unspecified value. You can fix the argument deduction bit by having two separate template parameters

```
template <class t, class u>
int compare(const t &a, const u &b) {
  if(a>b) return 1;
  if (a<b) return -1;

  return 0;
}
```

Clang gives a good error message

```
main1.cpp:17:5: error: no matching function for call to 'compare'
    compare("hi","world");
    ^~~~~~~
main1.cpp:4:5: note: candidate template ignored: 
  deduced conflicting types for parameter 't' ('char [3]' vs. 'char const[6]')
int compare(const t &a, const t &b) {
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, as in C, string literals are nul-terminated character arrays. `"hi"` becomes the character array `['h', 'i', 0]`. C++ treats the size of the array as part of its type for templates; the string `"hi"` is an array of length 3, and the string `"world"` is an array of length 6, so the compiler can't find a single type `t` that matches both arrays.

When you try to compile `compare("hi", "wo")` the compiler finds that type `t` is `const char [3]`, since both strings -- arrays -- have the same length.

When you drop the `&`, the arrays decode into const pointers, so the compiler finds that type `t` is `const char *`. Note that in this case, you're comparing the *pointers* to the strings, not their contents.

Answer (score 1):

Johannes Schaub - litb showed your problem.

And with that problem, one of the best solution for this case is using *Nontype Template Parameters*.

```
template <signed N, signed M>
int compare(const char (&p1) [N], const char (&p2) [M] ){
    return strcmp(p1, p2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the string literal "hi" is `const char [3]`.
The type of the string literal "world" is `const char [6]`.
So they're different types.

Your compare template uses the same type for both parameters, so this won't fly.

Change your compare template to use different types for the two parameters.
Also you will have to provide an overload to compare string literals correctly.

If you just write `(a>b)`, the arrays a and b will decay into pointers, so you'd be really only comparing the addresses of the first characters of the string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Template functions are *converted* into real function with template classes replaced with real classes by the compiler. In your code, your function prototype indicates that,

```
int compare(const t &a, const t &b)
```

both `a` and `b` must be of same type.

When you call `compare("hi", "world");`, for compiler there are two different types for `a` and `b` because "hi" is of type `const char [3]` and "world" is of type `const char [6]`. The compiler cannot implement a good version of `compare()`.

But when you call `compare("hi", "wo");`, suddenly both becomes of same type: `const char [3]` and there is no ambiguity.

If you implement the function as `int compare(const t a, const t b)` the compiler finds an alternative for t: `char *`. The arrays will be converted into `const char *` and thus there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If you **need** to have the comparison operators work in a template for C-style strings (null terminated arrays of `char`), you will have to have a specialized template along with your generic template.  **The thorn is that C-style strings cannot be compared using the operators.**

```
template <class t>
int compare(const char * a, const char * b)
{
  return strcmp(a, b);
}

template <class t>
int compare(const t& a, const t& b)
{
  return (a == b) ? 0 : ((a < b) ? -1 : 1);
}
```

**Note:  This templated function will fail for all classes that do not have `operator<` or `operator==` defined.**  Which will cause havoc down the road.  This looks very much like a using C++ templates to force things into the C language methodology.

### A Better Approach

I see two C++ specific features that could make your life easier:  Overloading operators and using `std::string`.  Using these features will eliminate your need for the templated functions.

### Overloading Operators

One reason for having a templated *compare* function is because the class doesn't have comparison operators devined (*otherwise you would use the operators*).  So, define the overloaded operators `<` and `==`.  The other operators `>, >=, <=` and `!=` can be defined in terms of the latter two.  See `boost` operators header.

### Using `std::string`

The problem of using comparison operators on C-style strings can be removed by replacing them with `std::string`.  A nice feature of `std::string` is that it has the comparison operators already defined.  Thus you can use `<` to compare two `std::string` objects.

### Summary

Rather than creating a template function that uses C-style comparing (e.g. return -1, 0, or +1), define comparison operators for your classes and convert null terminated arrays of characters into instances of `std::string`.

Comment: Nice explanation ! Just add my 2 cents. [Strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) return the difference. If we want match with the example we should do this : `return compare(strcmp(a, b), 0);`